# cannot invoke properties of control

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I'm trying to programmatically create a axWindowsMediaPlayer and show it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer wmplayer = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
        wmplayer.Size = new Size(200, 200);
        wmplayer.enableContextMenu = false; //here it throws an exception
        this.Controls.Add(wmplayer);
    }
```

but it says {Property set of 'enableContextMenu' cannot be invoked at this time.}

why is that? why can I set Size but not enableContextMenu?

Comment: try to set during construction, may it helps. try `new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer() { enableContextMenu = false };`

Comment: tried it out now, this crashed as well..

Comment: Maybe you have to show it first? That *invoked* thing could means there is no handle created yet. Try to enable context menu later by using another button. Works?

Comment: the show didn't help, but putting the contextmenu in another buttonfunction did... how can I though do the two right at creating?
I want the user to be able to add wmps but not to control them(also not if he wants it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

It is important that you do changes and/or function calls after you added wmplayer to this.Controls.
I don't know why wmplayer.Size worked, but it is definitively the exception..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer wmplayer = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
    this.Controls.Add(wmplayer);
    wmplayer.Size = new Size(200, 200);
    wmplayer.enableContextMenu = false; //here it throws an exception
}
```

works perfectly fine..